# Working with date ranges (Classic ASP and SQL)

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp-classic, vbscript

I have to implement a solution where two date ranges can overlap each other. within the overlapped dates, I have to count how many days overlap each other. Once I know the overlapped days I can calculate a total figure based on the price that's attached per day.

**A scenario would be that**

A customer is booking a hotel

Customer booking dates - 17/02/2011 to  26/02/2011

Normal price (All year) - 01/01/2011 - 31/12/2011 (price per day :$30.00)

Special Offer 1 dates - 01/01/2011 to 19/02/2011 (price per day :$20.00)

Special Offer 2 dates - 17/02/2011 to 24/02/2011 (price per day :$10.00)

In the above scenario, the proposed algorithm should work out the cheapest offer that the date ranges overlap and work out the price for the booking. If there is no special offer available it uses the normal price.

So for the first two days the system should get the price from "special offer 1" as it's the cheapest available price. Next 5 days should be "Special offer 2 price" and for the next 2 days it'll be normal price.

I'd be grateful to see both SQL(using MS-SQL Server) or Code base answers to get the diffrenet views.

I hope the question is clear and looking foward to see the answers.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please, let us know what rdbms are you using. SQLServer?

Comment: have you got any code or sql yet?

Comment: @Matt- I have got worked out the code for to get existing offers per "holiday property" as described above it is calculating the total with differnt variant of date ranges and offers that I'm struggling with. :-)

Comment: To my eye, the Special Offer 2 period is entirely contained in the Customer booking period, therefore I cannot tally your expected results with the actual data. Also, please confirm how many days you consider the period 17/02/2011 to 24/02/2011 to cover: 6, 7 or 8 days?

Comment: @onedaywhen - Sorry my mistake, I purely made up these dates to explain the solution. I would say if you change the "special offers 2 period" from 14/02/2011 to 19/02/2011. It will help to understand the overlaps bti clearer.

Comment: Your suggested change still doesn't make the data match the narrative. But I think I get the principle: I'll change the data to fit your narrative. I infer that you are using closed-open representation for periods i.e. the end data is not included in the period, therefore the period 17/02/2011 to 24/02/2011 is seven days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's supose that for each day you should apply lowest price.

```
create function price ( @fromDate date, @toDate date) returns money
as
begin
 declare @iterator_day date
 declare @total money
 set @total = 0
 set @iterator_day = @fromDate
 WHILE @iterator_day < = @toDate
 begin
    select @total = @total + min( price )
    from offers
    where @iterator_day  between offers.fromFay and offers.toDay
    set @iterator_day = DATEADD (day , 1 , @iterator_day )
 end
 return @total
end
```

then you can call function in your query:

```
select 
   b.fromDay, b.toDay, dbo.price( b.fromDay, b.toDay )
from 
   booking b
```

Comment: Loops are indeed AN answer, but in a set based language such as SQL, I'd seek out alternatives.

Comment: Many Thanks for all contributed I had to go with above as there's no room to restructure the model. As per performance, for now the systems only can have maximum of 3 special offers. Therefore, the performance drop is not signinficant.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard trick of using an [auxiliary calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html), it is simply a case of joins and grouping to get the best price each day:

```
SELECT C.dt, MIN(price) AS best_price
  FROM Prices P
       INNER JOIN Calendar C
          ON C.dt >= P.price_start_date 
             AND C.dt < P.price_end_date 
       INNER JOIN CustomerBooking B
          ON C.dt >= B.booking_start_date 
             AND C.dt < B.booking_end_date
 GROUP 
    BY C.dt;
```

The same query as above, including sample data using CTEs:

```
WITH Prices (price_start_date, price_end_date, narrative, price)
     AS 
     (
      SELECT CAST(start_date AS Date), CAST(end_date AS Date), narrative, price
        FROM (
              VALUES ('2011-01-01T00:00:00', '2011-12-31T00:00:00', 'Normal price', 30), 
                     ('2011-01-01T00:00:00', '2011-02-21T00:00:00', 'Special Offer 1', 20),
                     ('2011-02-19T00:00:00', '2011-02-24T00:00:00', 'Special Offer 2', 10)
             ) AS T (start_date, end_date, narrative, price)
     ), 
     CustomerBooking (booking_start_date, booking_end_date)
     AS 
     (
      SELECT CAST(start_date AS Date), CAST(end_date AS Date)
        FROM (
              VALUES ('2011-02-17T00:00:00', '2011-02-26T00:00:00')
             ) AS T (start_date, end_date)
     )     
SELECT C.dt, MIN(price) AS best_price
  FROM Prices P
       INNER JOIN Calendar C
          ON C.dt >= P.price_start_date 
             AND C.dt < P.price_end_date 
       INNER JOIN CustomerBooking B
          ON C.dt >= B.booking_start_date 
             AND C.dt < B.booking_end_date
 GROUP 
    BY C.dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only used ASP.net 4.0, but I can offer some SQL will give you the price for a given date:

```
SELECT     ISNULL(MIN(PricePerDay), 0) AS MinPricePerDay
FROM       Offers
WHERE     (StartDate <= '18/2/11') AND (EndDate >= '18/2/11')
```

From your application you could build the query to be something like this:

```
SELECT     ISNULL(MIN(PricePerDay), 0) AS MinPricePerDay
FROM       Offers
WHERE     (StartDate <= '17/2/11') AND (EndDate >= '17/2/11');
SELECT     ISNULL(MIN(PricePerDay), 0) AS MinPricePerDay
FROM       Offers
WHERE     (StartDate <= '18/2/11') AND (EndDate >= '18/2/11');
SELECT     ISNULL(MIN(PricePerDay), 0) AS MinPricePerDay
FROM       Offers
WHERE     (StartDate <= '19/2/11') AND (EndDate >= '19/2/11');
```

This would return a dataset of tables containing a single value for the minimum price for that date (in the same order as your query)

Sounds like a good job for a [Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you're got multiple overlapping time periods.  You either need to constrain the problem slightly, or remodel the data slightly.  (To get desirable performance.)

**Option 1 - Constraints**

- A data set of 'normal' prices - that never overlap with each other
- A data set of 'special' prices - that also never overlap with each other
- Every bookable date has a 'normal' price
- Every bookable date has a 'special' price (EVEN if it's NULL to mean 'no special price')

The last constraint is the strangest one.  But it's needed to make the simple join work.  When comparing date ranges, it's *alot* easier to form the query if the two sets of ranges are gapless and have no overlaps inside them.

This means that you should now be able to work it out with just a few joins...

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN [sp].started > [np].started THEN [sp].started ELSE [np].started END AS [started]
  CASE WHEN [sp].expired < [np].expired THEN [sp].expired ELSE [np].expired END AS [expired]
  CASE WHEN [sp].price   < [np].price   THEN [sp].price   ELSE [np].price   END AS [price]
FROM
  normal_prices          AS [np]
LEFT JOIN
  special_prices         AS [sp]
    ON  [sp].started <  [np].expired
    AND [sp].expired >  [np].started
    AND [sp].started >= (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(started),0) FROM special_prices WHERE started <= [np].started)
    --  The third condition is an optimisation for large data-sets.
WHERE
      [np].started < @expired
  AND [np].expired > @started

-- Note: Inclusive StartDates, Exlusive EndDate
--       For example, "all of Jan" would be "2011-01-01" to "2011-02-01"
```

**Option 2 - Re-Model**

This one is often the fastest in my experience; you increase the amount of space being used, and gain a simpler faster query...

```
Table Of Prices, stored by DAY rather than period...  
- calendar_date  
- price_code  
- price  

SELECT
  calendar_date,
  MIN(price)
FROM
  prices
WHERE
    calendar_date >= @started
AND calendar_date <  @expired
```

Or, if you needed the price_code as well...

```
WITH
  ordered_prices AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY calendar_date ORDER BY price ASC, price_code) AS price_rank,
    *
  FROM
    prices
)
SELECT
  calendar_date,
  price_code,
  price
FROM
  ordered_prices
WHERE
    calendar_date >= @started
AND calendar_date <  @expired
```

Comment: I like option 2 but rather than remodel one could transform from periods to day rates on the fly using a [calendar table](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html).

Comment: Agreed.  It does mean many records joining on to the period based data though.  As such joins (`start <= x AND end > x`) can be costly in large data-sets (due only filtering the index column by `<=`), remodeling *can* yield very noticeable benefits.  It all comes down to how many records `end > x` has to scan to get the records you're interested in.

Comment: Now added my own answer to demonstrate this approach. I agree you comments about performance and personally I'd take the hit of remodelling ;)